# How to change the User Agent String in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: internet-explorer

How to change the User Agent String in Internet Explorer 9 ?

Comment: not sure this is a c# question.

try this entry in the registry

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\User Agent

Comment: It depends on the IE version, read them all here: http://www.enhanceie.com/ua.aspx

Comment: use a third party transparent proxy like fiddler
http://www.fiddler2.com